# How to name a volume, created by Dockerfile

Tags: docker

If I start a container from an image, the Dockerfile of which has an entry like this:

```
VOLUME ["/data"]
```

with what subcommand of `docker run` should I start a container, so that when I list the volumes via `docker volume ls`, I see the name I gave to the volume and not some long random hash?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the ordinary `docker run -v` option to mount something on that same path, Docker won't create an anonymous volume there.

```
docker volume create something
docker run -v something:/data ...
```

In fact, you don't need a Dockerfile VOLUME directive to do this: you can mount a volume or host directory on to any container path regardless of whether or not it's declared as a VOLUME directory.  There's not a lot of benefits to having that in the Dockerfile, and it has some confusing side effects; I'd suggest just deleting that line.